# I don't understand freecodecamp challenge using objects for lookups

Tags: javascript, lookup-tables

I have a JavaScript challenge in freecodecamp that is probably really simple, but I still don't understand how to do it. It goes as follows:

```
// Setup
function phoneticLookup(val) {
  var result = "";

  // Only change code below this line
  switch(val) {
case "alpha": 
  result = "Adams";
  break;
case "bravo": 
  result = "Boston";
  break;
case "charlie": 
  result = "Chicago";
  break;
case "delta": 
  result = "Denver";
  break;
case "echo": 
  result = "Easy";
  break;
case "foxtrot": 
  result = "Frank";
  }

  // Only change code above this line
  return result;
}

// Change this value to test
phoneticLookup("charlie");
```

and it wants me to work out a way to look up any of the objects. I'm sure it's not a hard code, but I don't understand the explanation they give and no matter what I do, it still doesn't work and will come up with an 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression' which is really annoying. I am not allowed to use switch, case or if statements.
Pls help.

Comment: try this: 
console.log(phoneticLookup("charlie"));

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with javascript objects? Can you see how you'd use one to look up a key and return a value?

Comment: *Hint: A JavaScript object inherently has this functionality.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to covert the switch statement into an object:

```
lookup = {
    alpha: 'Adams',
    bravo: 'Boston',
    charlie: 'Chicago',
    delta: 'Denver',
    echo: 'Easy',
    foxtrot: 'Frank'
  };
```

Now that you have an object with keys and values you can get a values by using the key like this:

> lookup['charlie']  //which will = 'Chicago'
>
> lookup['echo']  //which will = 'Easy'

Since the key will be passed into the function as val you can now use the val to get the correct values associated with the key passed in.

```
return lookup[val]
```

Comment: Yeah thanks that works.I finally also worked out that to call it I would have to call var value, not var lookup e.g. var value("alpha")

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to steal the fun for you but I'm pretty sure they're eluding to this behavior of objects in javaScript

If I define an object like so:

```
var myObject = {
   one: "1",
   two: "2"
};
```

Then I can access the values by its index or key:

```
var firstVal = myObject["one"]
// firstVal is "1"
```

Hopefully that gets you on track while still giving you the chance to learn.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly refer to freecodecamp's vague `Expected` errors as "fun", but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the code challenge and although it looks pretty obvious it's quite easy to miss. First you convert the switch statement to an object lookup like this:

```
var lookup = {
    "alpha": "Adams",
    "bravo": "Boston",
    "charlie": "Chicago",
    "delta": "Denver",
    "echo": "Easy",
    "foxtrot": "Frank",    
}
```

to get to the values use 
    objectName.propertyName or objectName["propertyName"] 
in this case:

```
lookup["alpha"]; //"Adams"
lookup["bravo"]; //"Boston"
```

etc . then set the result variable to:

```
result = lookup[val]; //where val is defined in the function phoneticLookup(val).
```

Call function and voila!

Comment: Not really, the accepted answer works just fine but misses a key part of the code challenge where you're required to re-assign and return the result variable. The accepted answer makes no mention of result.

Comment: Have you considered that back in January, when this question was originally posted, the challenge might have been slightly different? OP was obviously happy with the accepted answer and said "it works".

Comment: Nope, not different at all, check the question, result = " ", also read my first reply. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

this is the only way to get it without modifying the return statement:

// Setup

function phoneticLookup(val) {

var result = "";

// Only change code below this line

var lookup = {

"alpha": "Adams",

"bravo": "Boston",

"charlie": "Chicago",

"delta": "Denver",

"echo": "Easy",

"foxtrot": "Frank",

};

return lookup[val];

// Only change code above this line
  return result;

}

// Change this value to test

phoneticLookup("charlie");

Answer (score 0):

```js
function phoneticLookup(val) {
  let result = "";

  const lookup = {
    "alpha": "Adams",
    "bravo": "Boston",
    "charlie": "Chicago",
    "delta": "Denver",
    "echo": "Easy",
    "foxtrot": "Frank"
  }
  result = lookup[val]
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Setup
function phoneticLookup(val) {
  let result = "";

  // Only change code below this line
  let lookup = {alpha: "Adams", bravo: "Boston", charlie: "Chicago", delta: "Denver", echo: "Easy", foxtrot: "Frank"};
  result = lookup[val];

  /*
  switch(val) {
    case "alpha":
      result = "Adams";
      break;
    case "bravo":
      result = "Boston";
      break;
    case "charlie":
      result = "Chicago";
      break;
    case "delta":
      result = "Denver";
      break;
    case "echo":
      result = "Easy";
      break;
    case "foxtrot":
      result = "Frank";
  }
  */

  // Only change code above this line
  return result;
}

console.log(phoneticLookup("charlie"));
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.